# pdf.js: how do I set options when using base64 encoded content

Tags: pdf, pdf.js

The Mozilla documents https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Viewer-options show that adding parameters to a url sets the browser extension options; however, I am retrieving an encoded string from the server - how do I set options in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: pdf.js does not handle base64 out-of-the-box due to subpar performance of the base64 encoding, convert it to Uint8Array or Blob before consuming it in the viewer. not all browsers understand data: schema

Comment: so once it is a blob, how does one set the options?

Comment: use URL.createObjectURL

Comment: I will take a look, thanks

Comment: it worked - though a complete answer would include a link on how to set up a blob